# Can visiting website infect computer?

Tags: malware, virus, chrome, macos, browser-hijacking

I have heard online that simply visiting a website can infect a computer. I had an instance recently where someone I know sent me a link but misspelled it. The misspelled link lead to a malicious website.

The misspelled link was:

**WARNING WEBSITE MIGHT BE MALICIOUS**

```
http://ww1.vassarstat.net
```

Which is a misspelling of [www.vassarstats.net](http://www.vassarstats.net)

I went there three times, each going to separate websites *(Note I've only included domains)*:

**WARNING WEBSITES MIGHT BE MALICIOUS**

```
http://briana.ttnrd.com/

http://iyfnzgb.com/

http://ww25.vassarstat.net/?z
```

I checked all on virus total and all came clean except `http://iyfnzgb.com/`

The results came as follows: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/ca060e0539d6866b634598b82bd0d64a82f8826779ec610a38e7939344ce398f/detection

For background information, I was using Google Chrome and had uBlock Origin installed. uBlock Origin gave the regular redirect warning however I thought the website was legit and ignored said warning. Once redirected, the website was completely blank. I'm guessing uBlock considered the content block-able or perhaps chrome blocked it. I am running macOS Big Sur. Chrome is up to date.

After the contact I ran Malwarebytes and checked Chrome for unusual activity (such as altered homepage, search engine, and extensions). Everything seemed normal.

Has my computer been comprised? What further steps should I take or have I done everything I should do?

Comment: We will not inspect those specific sites to determine if they are malicious or what they will do. However, I would recommend that you use something like a sandbox, like Cuckoo, to visit those sites since scans do not reveal everything.

Answer (score 0):

Install the "NoScript" plugin for Chrome which could add an extra layer of security by preventing drive-by attacks.
And the question whether your device is compromised would be hard to tell, keep an eye on unsual behaviour within your browser, keep your a/v up to date and if you have the ability to sniff your network traffic, you could examine whether there is C2 traffic.